# Azure DevOps Pipeline - triggering by tag but always on same branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to trigger a pipeline only when a new git tag is added, but being sure that the tag is on a specific branch.

As far as I understood the Azure DevOps predefined variables `Build.SourceBranch` and `Build.SourceBranchName` alternatively point to the current tag or the current branch depending on what have triggered the pipeline execution.

So I cannot use those variables to understand if the tag has been added within the same branch.

Do you think is it possible, during the pipeline execution, check if we are on a specific tag and branch together?
Does the thing make sense?

Comment: Tags don't go on "branches". Tags go on commits. Although a commit may be reachable from a certain branch, a commit may also be reachable from many branches.

Comment: How do you plan to trigger your build based on a tag?

Comment: In my case tags are used to version the deployments and branches define what environment target (PROD/TEST/DEV) - I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Their seems no direct solution for this. [According to MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags), after specifying branch & tag filter together for trigger in a same pipeline, then the pipeline will trigger if either of the conditions are matched.

To achieve what you are looking for, you can create a custom pre-validation stage.
This stage could contain a PowerShell/Shell script:

1. to check IF the trigger happened from a specific branch that you need - by using the `build.SourceBranch/build.BanchName` variable
2. to check IF the tag is the required tag on that specific branch - tag name can be found by : `startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')`

Based on results of the stage above, you can then decide to skip the downstream stages or execute them.

Hope this helps :)